# Dynamic Menu in Django using database mysql

Tags: django

I have  tables tbl_menu,  tbl_role,  tbl_role_menu_mapping in mysql

[image: table-menu]
 [image: tbl_role_menu_mapping]

I am unable to make a dynamic menu in my Django project using MySQL which could be applicable for whole application for all apps, All examples are given for static menu for a separate app. While we want to bind according to the role. So how can bind dynamic according to the role which will be applicable to all apps

Comment: Please provde the code where you tried to show menu in the template and showing your view function will be fine.

Comment: you are asking for creating "dynamic menu according to the role" but you didn't showed any code or example of roles on what and how you want to perform or what result you desire.

Comment: I have no idea how we could create